# how to insert arraylist in single coloumn one by one using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello sir i send the arraylist through url pass from android to php all array list is inserted to one row in single coloumn . i want inserted one column(menuname) to multiple rows

```
          EG:
      i pass array list[x,y,z.........] android to php

        mysql 
       menuname
        x
        y
        z(i want like this)

  i try this code

   <?php
   $arr[]=$_POST['menuname'];
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","mobixmysql");
   mysql_select_db("test");
   foreach($arr as $value){
   $value;
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (menuname) VALUES ('" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "')")or
   die('unable'.mysql_error());
   echo "inserted";
   }
   ?>
```

i try above code it insert the database in menuname column in one row . i want add multiple rows in one column

Comment: maybe `$arr=$_POST['menuname'];`

Comment: and  what you want from `$value;` string right after foreach;

Comment: $value is inserted into one row in mysql database as like array. arr[0] insert one row arr[1] inserted into another row please tell me

Comment: i mean why last value in that block
`foreach($arr as $value){
   $value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `$_POST['menuname']` is not array;

```
<?php
   $arr=explode(',',preg_replace('/^.*\[(.*)\].*$/','$1',$_POST['menuname']));
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","mobixmysql");
   mysql_select_db("test");
   foreach($arr as $value){
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (menuname) VALUES ('" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "')")or
   die('unable'.mysql_error());
   echo "inserted";
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: so `$_POST['menuname']` is not array, how you post your 'menuname' ?

Comment: `echo $_POST['menuname']` should help to understand

Comment: What is result when `echo $_POST['menuname']` ?  If it is not array make it to array then proceed ...

Comment: [Food Menu,Catalog.Deals on Meal] this my array is pass to php

Comment: i copy past ur code means it shows error  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in like this please see

Comment: really thanks ur code works fine. but [start ]end this brakets are inserted  i want remove it

Comment: please note, not to use such in production :)

Comment: sir i want remove start[ and ].. please tell me how

Comment: seems the [] not placed as i expect, read preg_replace doc on php.net